# Universality with Toffoli + Hadamard

Tags: gate-synthesis, universal-gates

If I take the two gates Hadamard and Toffoli, then it is clear that I cannot simulate an arbitrary $n$ qubit unitary on $n$ qubits because both matrices are real, so there's no access to the complex space. However, I can simulate any $n$ qubit unitary on $n+1$ qubits (to arbitrary accuracy), using the extra qubit to effectively flag amplitudes as real or imaginary.

Now, however, imagine I allow you Toffoli and the set of Clifford gates, particularly $S$. The real/complex argument no longer works because of this $S$ gate. So: how many qubits do I need to simulate an $n$-qubit unitary to arbitrary accuracy using this gate set? $n+1$ is certainly sufficient, but can I get away with just $n$? How do I prove it either way?

Comment: Could it start off being $n+1$ then close to $n$ in the limit as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @MarkS You need an integer number of qubits, so it's either $n$ or $n+1$. I suppose there *could* be a threshold value of $n$ where it transitions.

Comment: @MarkS I suppose that there would *have* to be that transition somewhere. Given that we only obtain universality by adding Toffoli to Clifford, we necessarily require 3 qubits to simulate, for example, a 2-qubit non-Clifford gate.

Comment: What is the answer for other discrete universal gate sets?

Comment: You will need to define what you mean by "simulate". In the Hadamard + Toffoli setting, this notion of simulation seems to be a different one than the one you are potentially after in your question. Can you specify what you demand from "simulation"? -- In any case, it seems what you want to understand is the algebra generated by this gate set on a given number of qubits.